# "He started paying Carol to look after me"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Can anybody help me understand this sentence?

> He started paying Carol to look after me...

Does it literally mean he started to give her money for looking after me or is there some other meaning of this phrase?

Comment: I don't think there's any hidden meaning. 'After my mother died, he [my father] started paying Carol [a nanny] to look after me.'

Answer (score 1):

It could be a son who started paying Carol to look after his ailing father/mother or any such relation.
Carol could have been doing it voluntarily, after which he started paying her.

A context would help but it is as simple as it reads.

Comment: Yes; the less literal usages are of the form 'it pays to brush your teeth every day' / 'it paid to look after their ageing father themselves'.